# Informatica Code to SQL Code

Tags: sql-server, database, transformation, etl, informatica

I am transforming the following informatica code to SQL. I am encountering some issues and would appreciate help with the following code: 
SUBSTR(COV_REINS_CONCAT_BK,INSTR(COV_REINS_CONCAT_BK,'|',1,3) +1,2)

That is, I am looking for the equivalent code to produce the same results in SQL Server.

I appreciate anyone's help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SUBSTR's equivalent is [SUBSTRING](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx).

INSTR's equivalent is [CHARINDEX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx), but it has the first 2 parameters reversed, and does not support the 4th parameter (occurrence).

The expression returns 2 characters after the third occurrence of | (pipe).
*Example*: It will return 'FG' for 'A|BC|DE|FGH'.

So the translation will be:

```
SUBSTRING(COV_REINS_CONCAT_BK,1+CHARINDEX('|',COV_REINS_CONCAT_BK,1+CHARINDEX('|'
  ,COV_REINS_CONCAT_BK,1+CHARINDEX('|',COV_REINS_CONCAT_BK))),2)
```

Comment: Hi Cosmin, thanks so much for your help. the code works perfectly. Would you be able to help with the following; it is similar to the above code, however, it is nonetheless a little more complicated: LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTR(COV_REINS_CONCAT_BK,11, INSTR(COV_REINS_CONCAT_BK, '|',1,3)-INSTR(COV_REINS_CONCAT_BK, '|',1,2)-1 ))) || 'C'

Comment: It becomes increasingly difficult to port such expressions that make extensive use of INSTR using the occurrence parameter.
Maybe it's easier to create in your MS-SQL database an INSTR equivalent function that supports the occurrence parameter. See how here: http://www.sqlines.com/oracle/functions/instr
Then the expression from the comment becomes much easier to translate: LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(COV_REINS_CONCAT_BK,11,dbo.INSTR(COV_REINS_CONCAT_BK,'|',1,3)-dbo.INSTR(COV_REINS_CONCAT_BK,'|',1,2)-1 )))+'C'
Here SUBSTR becomes SUBSTRING, and INSTR becomes dbo.INSTR and concatenation || will be +.